# Sql Compare and Update

Tags: sql, sql-server

Selecting rows in a table,comparing one column between yesderday and today if that column of today value is not equal to yesderaday's value hence other column in a table should be updated as 'Changed' or 'No Change'...
Any suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

Use a self join between same table.

```
SELECT *, 
       CASE 
         WHEN a.value = b.value THEN 'Not' 
         ELSE 'Changed' 
       END AS Modified 
FROM   MyTable a 
       INNER JOIN MyTable b 
         ON Dateadd(d, -1, a.mydate) = b.mydate
```